memory pool tx question
At present, I have encountered some problems. I listen to newPendingtransaction to obtain the pending transaction in the memory pool, listen to the method of adding liquidity, and send the transaction when I hear it. If the gasPrice is larger than the transaction adding liquidity, there will be a false start, which should not occur. It will appear that the purchase is not in the same block to add liquidity, and if the Settings are the same, it may appear in the same block, or it may be in the next block. How do I solve this problem to ensure that my transaction must be in the same block behind the liquidity transaction?
